# Lock acquisition order?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand an example of multithreading:

```
class Callme {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print(msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Callme target;

    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }

    public Caller(Callme target, String msg) {
        this.target = target;
        this.msg = msg;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (target) {
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Callme target = new Callme();
        new Caller(target, "1");
        new Caller(target, "2");
        new Caller(target, "3");
        new Caller(target, "4");
    }
}
```

The output is `1432`. Why isn't it `1234`? What is the order of lock acquisition on "target"? I thought it should work like this:

1. First "Caller" object gets lock on "target" object - prints "1" and sleeps for 1s (blocking other threads to execute target.call(msg))
2. After 1s of sleep first "Caller" releases lock and then next (second?) "Caller" object gets lock on "target" object - prints "2" and sleeps for 1s

And so on. Where is the mistake in my thinking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't the calls in main sequential?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563287/why-arent-the-calls-in-main-sequential)

Answer (score 1):

Point to note here is, `synchronized` does not guarantee order of execution. What it guarantees is that object that is locked will not be modified by any other thread till `synchronized` finishes.

There is no guarantee of sequence of locks that will be taken in multithreading.

There can be a case, thread 1 is struck/slept even before it gets in `synchronized` block.

Comment: Ok - if there is no guarantee of sequence of locks why am I always getting result as above? If so - the result and thus order of threads should by random, but it isn't.